# UITextField cursor position on edit always at the end of text

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

In Safari, if I type in "foobar" into a textfield on any website, close my keyboard, and then tap on the middle of the "foobar" between o and b, the cursor of the text field starts in between o and b.

In my app, I'm using a standard `UITextField`. When I type in an email foo@bar.com and attempt to tap on the @ sign, the cursor begins at the end of the text (after the ".com"). How do I make the cursor begin at the position of where I tapped like in Safari?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663614/how-to-move-cursor-of-uitextview-to-touched-location